# For int8 var, how to understand "-128 / -1" and "-128 * -1" results are -128?

Tags: go

Just started learning Go a few weeks ago and the behavior is very confusing to me.

```
var n int8 = -128

n /= -1
fmt.Println(n)

n *= -1
fmt.Println(n)
```

The above [code](https://play.golang.org/p/BWSOUGotWTL) would both output `-128`. I also tried `-64 * -2` which also resulted in `-128`.

Is the value `-128` special which means int *overflow* here?

Comment: `-128` is not an overflow, but `128` is. The result of evaluation is not representible with `int8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a special value that is used on overflow, it's just the minimum value of a signed 8 bit integer (the valid range is `[-128, 128)`, meaning -128 is included, but 128 is not).

In simple cases such as incrementing the maximum value (eg: `int8(127) + 1`), you overflow the integer and end up with the smallest value.

In Go, this is perfectly acceptable, as mentioned by the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)

> For signed integers, the operations +, -, *, /, and << may legally
> overflow and the resulting value exists and is deterministically
> defined by the signed integer representation, the operation, and its
> operands. Overflow does not cause a run-time panic. A compiler may not
> optimize code under the assumption that overflow does not occur. For
> instance, it may not assume that x < x + 1 is always true.

But your specific case is different and is due to the fact that **taking the two's-complement of the most negative value returns the same value**.

The simplest example is this one:

```golang
    var n int8 = -128
    fmt.Println(-n)
    // output -128
```

This is because flipping all the bits and adding 1 returns exactly the same:

```
  // Start with -128
  n = 1000 0000
  // Flip bits:
  n = 0111 1111
  // Add 1:
  n = 1000 0000
```

Oops! This means that `-(-128) == -128`.

The same applies to multiplication and division: `-1 * (-128) == -128`.
In the case of division, the result is undefined in some languages.
Rather than leave this ambiguity, the Go [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) spells out this special case:

> ... if the dividend x is the most
> negative value for the int type of x, the quotient q = x / -1 is equal
> to x (and r = 0) due to two's-complement integer overflow

You can find more information about two's complement arithmetic on Wikipedia, with a section devoted to [the most negative number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Most_negative_number).

Comment: Nah, it's fair, we're used to overflow with addition/subtraction, it gets a bit weirder when you do multiplication and division.